# How to display Link url as plain text which is added from ck-editor link element?

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I want display the link url as plain text witch added by link element from ck-editor .

below is my code

```
var medsims_val = '{external_link{imageurl:"[medsims_img_url]", linkurl:"[medsims_link]", expiry_date:"[medsims_link_expiry]",caption:"[medsims_caption_text]"}}';
var medsims_field_val = this.getValueOf('info', 'medsims_img_url');
  medsims_val = medsims_val.replace("[medsims_img_url]", (medsims_field_val ? medsims_field_val.trim() : ''));
  medsims_field_val = this.getValueOf('info', 'medsims_link');
  medsims_val = medsims_val.replace("[medsims_link]", (medsims_field_val ? medsims_field_val.trim() : ''));
  medsims_field_val = this.getValueOf('info', 'medsims_link_expiry');
  medsims_val = medsims_val.replace("[medsims_link_expiry]", (medsims_field_val ? medsims_field_val.trim() : ''));
  medsims_field_val = this.getValueOf('info', 'medsims_caption_text');
  medsims_val = medsims_val.replace('[medsims_caption_text]', (medsims_field_val ? medsims_field_val.trim() : ''));
var text = CKEDITOR.tools.trim(medsims_val);
  CKEDITOR.plugins.link.getSelectedLink(editor).setText(text);
```

Any help how to get the saving data plain text ?

Answer (score 0):

For printing content that contains those links find template where that text is printed and print it through  strip_tags() php funciton to filter out the tags.

And you can configure widget type of that field - change text format to plain text. Or even create your on text format, specify which that you want to keep and which to remove and use that filter for that field. That way newly created node must use your field as you defined, but previously defined won't change their content automatically. To do that:

You could also make some script to read all nodes in content type you are using, read field value, pass it to strip_tags and save it back to database.